# Sharing web page url to Facebook

Tags: facebook, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I try to share a web page url with `NSSharingServicePicker` to Facebook, but it appears on my FB wall not as a web page url(with description and so on), but just like a link.

My code is very simple.

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/travel-route-planner/id504536611"];

    NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url, nil]];
    sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;

    [sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[shareButton bounds]
                                      ofView:shareButton
                               preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

I know it could be done.
Safari shares web pages the way i need.

Comment: Have you tried to include an image? Safari always includes the thumbnail of the website you're sharing. Perhaps that changes something? I only ever shared to Facebook via the Facebook SDK. If I remember correctly that WHAT changed the HOW of sharing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Didn't help. Usually the image and description are taken from the web page via Graph API.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the URL as an NSString instead of an NSURL?

Comment: Try passing msg as first item, ie. `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: msg, url, nil]`

Comment: Try implementing a NSSharingServiceDelegate for the Facebook service and setting the `sharingContentScope` to `NSSharingContentScopeFull` in `-sharingService:sourceWindowForShareItems:sharingContentScope`. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSharingServiceDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSSharingServiceDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on Apple Dev forums.

You need to add image to NSURL using following NSSharingServiceDelegate methods

```
- (NSRect) sharingService: (NSSharingService *) sharingService
sourceFrameOnScreenForShareItem: (id<NSPasteboardWriting>) item
{
    if([item isKindOfClass: [NSURL class]])
    {
        //return a rect from where the image will fly
        return NSZeroRect;
    }

    return NSZeroRect;
}

- (NSImage *) sharingService: (NSSharingService *) sharingService
 transitionImageForShareItem: (id <NSPasteboardWriting>) item
                 contentRect: (NSRect *) contentRect
{
    if([item isKindOfClass: [NSURL class]])
    {

        return [NSImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

don't forget to set the delegate for your NSSharingService

```
- (id < NSSharingServiceDelegate >)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker delegateForSharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService
{
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the source code on the website you're trying to share, and ran it through the [Facebook Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/travel-route-planner/id504536611). Facebook is pretty picky when it comes to the defined protocol, so I'd recommend changing your URL from `http://` to `https://` as the secure URL is what iTunes has decided to set as their `og:url` property. See [here](http://cl.ly/image/3t1v2n172l0v):

Comment: Didn't help. sorry. I see in Safari web page is shared like an image, with no url in message text, but in my case web page url is always in message text.